How to keep Ledfx and Moode Audio from blocking audio output device
I have a Raspberry Pi with a Hifiberry Amp4 that runs Moode Audio OS.
If I pick Pulse as they audio device in LedFx and play a sound file with aplay sound_file.wav my leds react to the music.
The problem is that after aplay has finished playing the sound file if I then go try to use Moode audio player Moode audio won't play music and gives me the following error:
MPD error Failed to open "ALSA Default" (alsa); Failed to open ALSA device "_audioout": Device or resource busy
This persists until I stop Ledfx. Is there a way I can switch back and forth between aplay and Moode Audio player without having to stop and start Ledfx? I am not looking to get LedFx working with Moode I only want reactive lights when I play a song with aplay.
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sndrpihifiberry [snd_rpi_hifiberry_dacplus], device 0: HiFiBerry DAC+ HiFi pcm512x-hifi-0 [HiFiBerry DAC+ HiFi pcm512x-hifi-0]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
